# Why does Moe Greene speak with a strange voice?

Tags: dialogue, the-godfather, editing

In *The Godfather*, why is Moe Greene's line "I talked to Barzini" given in such as strange voice?

I heard it was dubbed but why would it be?

Comment: Where did you hear it was dubbed? There's a kind of dubbing called "looping" just to replace dialogue from the same actor where the recorded sound wasn't *quite* right the first time. - http://filmsound.org/terminology/adr.htm

Comment: @Paulie_D in the Youtube description it says "overdub fail". Can you explain a bit more? So out of all the takes the actor said the line so poorly it was worse than this? That's hard to believe. And for such a big budget film they got a different actor to do the voice over?

Comment: A Youtube comment is not an **authoritative** source. If you have something more official then that's different but it just sounds to me as though Alex Rocco was using his *emphasis* voice.

Comment: My guess, is the actor did not prononce "Barzini" correctly, so the had to overdub it, later in a studio. Then they had to morph the word Barzini, and melt it in the actual dialogue, which created some distortion and pitch variation.

Comment: To me it seems like a single take of a good performance, in which an actor suggests that the character is "choked up." The character's voice is quavering with emotion.

Comment: I just saw a YouTube comment stating "They add in extra lines to make the plot clearer if people find the plot too confusing in post-production." (by  harizotoh7
harizotoh7) does anyone know if this is true?

Comment: It sounds precisely like Tessio to me, very much as with [this scene](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CZswDXmWIAEDGY6.jpg) during the funeral.  I have to wonder if there was an intentional foreshadowing here that somehow stayed under the radar, but given how the GF1 has been analyzed up down left and right for so long, I find that hard to believe.  It remains a bit of a headscratcher to me all this time.

Answer (score -2):

From my brief experience on a set, it could have been something as simple as an off-scene noise that messed up the audio at that moment. But of all the retakes, this one had something ***more*** important to the director, so they overdubbed the muffed audio as the lesser of two "evils".

Comment: Is this speculation, or do you have a source for this explanation?

Comment: As I said, I had a brief experience on the set of a movie ("The Candidate", with Robert Redford, as an extra) and observed this happening. They shot a particular scene maybe a dozen times for a variety of reasons, mostly because there was some particular "look" that the director was after. In one shoot, the director cried out about how "perfect" it was (for whatever he was looking for) but the sound man came back and said there was a noise on the audio track. The director told the audio guy that they were going to use it, and he can dub in the audio from another shoot.

Comment: I appreciate your experience, but without source that this was what harmed in Godfather, this becomes pure speculation that that is what they did, based off the reasoning in another movie.